# BASH sed does not evaluate array

Tags: bash

So i have an array with filenames.

```
for i in "${!array_FILE[@]}"; do 
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${array_FILE[$i]}"
  sed -e "s/\${USERNAME_VAR}/$USERNAME_VAR/" -e "s/\${USERNAME}/$USERNAME/" template > array_FILE[$i].js
done
```

The printf works and gives me

```
0       app_calander
1       app_contacts
2       app_search
3       app_index
```

but the files created are:

```
array_FILE[0].js
array_FILE[1].js
array_FILE[2].js
array_FILE[3].js
```

instead of

```
app_calander.js
app_contacts.js
app_search.js
app_index.js
```

If you can help me i appreciate it, it has to be changed by **index** because i have two array and i need to change values at the same index.

My temporary solution is:

```
filename="${array_FILE[$i]}"
sed -e "s/\${USERNAME_VAR}/$USERNAME_VAR/" -e "s/\${USERNAME}/$USERNAME/" template > $filename.js
```

but i was wondering if there is a better way!

**REAL ISSUE**

Now the real issue is when i try to pass a URL

```
for i in "${!array_FILE[@]}"; do 
  #printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${array_FILE[$i]}"
  filename="${array_FILE[$i]}"
  url="${array_URL[$i]}"
  sed -e "s/\${USERNAME_VAR}/$USERNAME_VAR/" -e "s/\${USERNAME}/$USERNAME/" -e "s/\${URL}/'$url'/" template > $filename.js
done

sed: -e expression #3, char 18: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #3, char 18: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #3, char 18: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #3, char 18: unknown option to `s'
```

sample value of `url` is `URL:https://example.com/app/index.html`

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION**

**data.txt**

```
USERNAME_VAR:input_username
USERNAME:user01
PASSWORD_VAR:input_password
PASSWORD:password1
SUBMIT:submit
AUTH:cas
URL:https://example.com/app/calander.html
FILE:app_calander
URL:https://example.com/app/contacts.html
FILE:app_contacts
URL:https://example.com/app/search.html
FILE:app_search
URL:https://example.com/app/index.html
FILE:app_index
```

**template**

```
${USERNAME_VAR} = ${USERNAME}
${SUBMIT} IS TRUE
${PASSWORD_VAR} = ${PASSWORD}
${AUTH} = AUTH IS
URL TO HIT IS ${URL}
```

**inject.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME_VAR=($(grep -o 'USERNAME_VAR.*' data.txt | cut -f2- -d':'))
USERNAME=($(grep -o 'USERNAME.*' data.txt | grep -v 'VAR.*' | cut -f2- -d':'))
echo $USERNAME_VAR
echo $USERNAME

array_URL=($(grep -o 'URL.*' data.txt | cut -f2- -d':'))
array_FILE=($(grep -o 'FILE.*' data.txt | cut -f2- -d':'))

for i in "${!array_FILE[@]}"; do 
  #printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${array_FILE[$i]}"
  FILENAME="${array_FILE[$i]}"
  URL="${array_URL[$i]}"
  echo $URL
  sed -e "s/\${URL}/$URL/" -e "s/\${USERNAME_VAR}/$USERNAME_VAR/" -e "s/\${USERNAME}/$USERNAME/" template > $FILENAME.js
done
```

Comment: You do understand your `sed` expression is evaluating like `sed -e "s/\${USERNAME_VAR}/variablevalue/"`. I doubt you want `\${USERNAME_VAR}` which searches for a *literal* `'${USERNAME_VAR}'` (you might, it just looks odd). You also need to fix `template > array_FILE[$i].js` to `template > ${array_FILE[$i]}.js` Your `sed` error is most likely in the expansion of `'$url'`

Comment: @DavidC. Rankin it works fine. It's looking for the literal `${USERNAME_VAR}` and replacing it with the value of `$USERNAME_VAR` which is `input_username`. The `USERNAME` and `USERNAME_VAR` works fine! It's the `-e "s/\${URL}/$URL/"` that throws an error. I am replacing values in a template file which has those literals as placeholders :)

Comment: That makes sense. Your issue is in the expansion of `URL:https://example.com/app/index.html`. Enclosing `$url` in single-quotes is not a solution. You need to change the `sed` separators to `#` (or something similar) e.g. `-e "s#\${URL}#$url#"`

Comment: @David C. Rankin Thank you! It was the separator! :) `-e "s#\${URL}#$URL#"` works now

Comment: Sure, that's is one that often bites me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from the comment, you could do something like:

```
for i in "${!array_FILE[@]}"; do 
    #printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${array_FILE[$i]}"
    filename="${array_FILE[$i]}"
    url="${array_URL[$i]}"
    sed -e "s#\${USERNAME_VAR}#$USERNAME_VAR#" \
    -e "s#\${USERNAME}#$USERNAME#" \
    -e "s#\${URL}#$url#" template > $filename.js
done
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The answer to the first question is staring right at you: `"${array_FILE[$i]}"` is obviously different from `"array_FILE[$i]"`
2. To understand the "REAL ISSUE", just look at the error messages. They  are telling you the problem is with the third sed expression, which assumes that $url does not have a "/" in it.
3. Unless you are certain that $USERNAME, $USERNAME_VAR and $url do not have "/" in them, then those sed commands will not work in the way you seem to expect.